How can I run undetected-chromedriver in headless mode without the website detecting it and triggering a CAPTCHA?
I am unable to run this script in headless mode:
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome(headless=True,use_subprocess=False)


try this
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless=True
options.add_argument('--headless')

scrap = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True,options=options)

